# Map fields of three different classes to a json object and then create a string from that json

Tags: java, json

I have three different classes (e.g. X, Y, and Z) with some fields/variables. After setting values of these fields, i would like to map them to a JSON object. And then this JSON object should be converted to a String value. How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javax.json to map a class into a json object and then use the toString to obtain the string of the json object built.

```
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.json.JsonObjectBuilder;

public String getString(CustomClass custom) {
        JsonObjectBuilder customBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder();

        customBuilder.add("param1", custom.getParam1())
                    .add("param2", custom.getParam2());

        JsonObject customJsonObject = customBuilder.build();

        return customJsonObject.toString();
    }
```

Comment: `javax.json` is not part of the standard Java API.  You need to caveate that in your answer.  It is part of `maven`which the OP did not add a tag for.